# How to save array request in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

my table

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('productname');
$table->string('qty');
$table->string('price');
$table->string('priceinword');
$table->timestamps();
```

form is coming to controller like this

```
  array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "za1Pzkwihk7trQcf2xWIxVjIzPBycl5Ix8dYYTjD"
  "productname" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "product 1"
    1 => "product 2"
  ]
  "qty" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
  ]
  "price" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "123"
    1 => "321"
  ]
  "priceinword" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "one two three"
    1 => "three two one"
  ]
]
```

how to save data to products table in array
how to solve this query

Comment: using foreach save data in array and insert in DB : Model::insert($data);

Answer (score 0):

use for

```
for($i = 0; i<count($request->productname); $i++)
{
    Product::create([
        'productname' => $request->productname[$i],
        'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Product model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
   public $table = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
   protected $primaryKey = 'YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY';

   protected $fillable = ['productname','qty','price','priceinword'];
}
```

In controller:

```
Product::create($request->all());
```

**OR**

Product model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
   public $table = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
   protected $primaryKey = 'YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY';
}
```

In controller:

```
$model = new Product;
$model->productname = $request->productname;
$model->qty = $request->qty;
$model->price = $request->price;
$model->priceinword = $request->priceinword;
$model->save();
```

Make sure you write database column names correctly.

Comment: what is primary key

Comment: Primary key of your table in the database, that would be I guess "id"

Comment: i want to save multiple data in array for example productname coming 2 name product 1 and product 2 also coming product 1 qty is 2 product 2 qty 2

Comment: You can try converting your array into string and then store it into the database. Use implode() function to convert array into strings and then you can store it in the database. While getting data from database, you can use explode() function to convert string into array.

Comment: You will easily get proper demo of those functions on w3schools.com . That would be more helpful clearing your concepts of these two functions.

Answer (score -2):

Product model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
}
```

In controller you may do this:

```
$model = new Product($request->all());
$model->save();
```

Or this:

```
Product::create($request->all());
```

Comment: setting up `$table` is only required if you do not want to follow Laravel table naming convention.

Comment: Undefined variable: array

Comment: @SidHeart $array is your data from form

Comment: $product =  new Product(array($request));
        $product->productname = $request->productname;
        $product->qty = $request->qty;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->priceindword = $request->priceindword;
        $product->save();

Comment: @SidHeart and? as you wish you may change any property of model, or use Product::create($request->all());

Comment: @J.Doe i never did this before i can't understand getting unknown errors can you write down full code Like $product = Product::create($request->all()); $product->productname = ??;

Comment: @SidHeart $product->productname = ?? what do you mean? update answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174936/discussion-between-sid-heart-and-j-doe).

Comment: @J.Doe trying to solve since morning still not working